# h:selectManyListbox validation for not being empty

Tags: validation, jsf-2, bean-validation

I have an initially empty `h:selectManyListbox` that before submitting my page must contain at least one entry. So I thought to put a validation to check this.
I tried with

```
@Size( min = 1, message = "{validation.emptyDataOptions}" )
private Set< DataOption > dataOptions;
```

in the bean and with `required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.validationEmptyFund}"` in the page.

The first has no effect and the second only if before submitting the page I select at least one entry.

Do I miss something?
Is there a possibility to only check if a `h:selectManyListbox` is not empty?

Here is the code:

```
<td>
  <h:selectManyListbox
    id       = "dataOptions"
    value    = "#{detailModel.selectedDataOptions}" size="5"
    readonly = "#{detailModel.mode == detailModel.viewMode or (detailModel.mode == detailModel.editMode and !loggedUser.hasPermission('CMN backoffice permission id'))}"
    required = "true" requiredMessage="#{msg.validationEmptyFund}"
  >
    <f:selectItems
      value = "#{detailModel.afterObject.dataOptions}"
      var   = "sdo" itemLabel="#{sdo.dataOptionName}" itemValue="#{sdo}"
    />
  </h:selectManyListbox>
  <h:messages for="dataOptions" style="color:red; font-size:12px;" />
</td>
```